# C++ Stack Declaration Issue

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to declare a stack in my program, however it says I can't declare it the way I'm trying to.

```
private:
    stack<tree_node<T>*> s;
```

Then I try to use it as follows:

```
 protected:
     s.push(p);
```

Note: there is more code in the "protected" section, but this is where the error is coming from.

`error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘stack’ with no type`

Comment: Do you have `#include <stack>`? Do you have either `using namespace std;` or `using std::stack;`? Is `tree_node` a complete type? What type is `p` in `s.push(p);`? What a ridiculously incomplete question...

Comment: Most likely, `stack` isn't in scope. Are you sure you don't mean `std::stack`?

Comment: Also, `s.push(p);` appears to be in a class definition rather than in a class member function or constructor. Any chance you can show the complete class definition?

Comment: You need to post some more code illustrating your question, or it's very likely to be closed...

Comment: Also, please post more of your code. It is impossible to debug as it is.

Comment: @aib yes, this was the issue, thanks

Answer (score 1):

At least in a typical case, the `<T>` only make sense inside a template where `T` is declared as one of the template parameters, something like:

```
template<class T>
class whatever // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here, from what you've posted, is that you are attempting to put naked code in the class declaration.  You put implementation details in a function.

This is wrong:

```
class foo{
    int bar;
protected:
    bar = 3;
};
```

This is correct:

```
class foo{
    int bar;
protected:
    void setBar(){ bar = 3; }
]:
```

Comment: No, I only wrote it that way in order to show how I was trying to use the stack. It is actually used how you requested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with not having std::stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> protected:
>        s.push(p);

do you mean you are trying to write this inside the class declaration (the .h file)?
You have already declared the stack, to use you need to do so inside the definition of a member function.

Also, as mentioned by Jerry Coffin, unless you have typedef-ed "T" to a user type, you should replace it with the actual type you will use. Or make the whole class a template class...

You say you have more code in the "protected" area, perhaps you should post that as well and also explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
stack<tree_node<T>>* s;
```

or are you tryin to create a stack of tree node pointers?